# VBA to write data into Excel used by multiple users on a network?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ado

Basically I have a master workbook on a network drive which is used by many to update the sheet, I want to automate this, through my research I found there are many complications with it if I automate it.

Searching on Google gave me the following suggestions and I have noted some complications with these solutions

1. using VBA open and write data and close it.

   - **there are chances that Excel is already opened by others and it is in read only mode**, so I can't write. Even though I tried open and write  but it's taking too long getting stuck.
2. Share the workbook and write data

   - for this to happen the workbook should be opened and shared by one at least, while writing data if two people are writing data at a time there is a chance that **one could overwrite data of others**
3. using ADO write data into Excel

   - I **don't have any idea about ADO and how it can be used to write data into Excel**, saw some examples and ended up nothing to comprehend.

Comment: What type of data do you need to store ? You could use Access to provide users with an interface to enter  data and have your master report pull data from that database when someone needs to produce reports of some sort.

Comment: This whole thing just sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur its only dates,status and few strings...i think wat u told makes sense,i have created interface to update access database.But getting data to the master sheet,i couldn't achieve, i dont know how to go about it. Its not for producing reports. one guy works on mastersheet whole day, this is kind of job submisssion(we will update in mastersheet and he will work on the jobs updated and he will mark status of job inmastersheet). how to get the new records inserted in database into the mastersheet and append in last row automatically.

Comment: There's an option 4.  Use a database.

Comment: @TobyAllen yes i have created databse..but retrieveing it to excel sett foor viewing is a problem can u give me example code for it

Answer (score 0):

- Set up an Access database
- Connect to the database from an Excel: Go to the ribbon: Data > From Access. This almost works like a pivot table and is indeed view only.

You can also store all the data still in an Excel and again use the External Data options (From Other Sources > Wizard > Other/Advanced > (tab) Connection > Use data source name > Excel Files > OK) to connect to it from a central Excel that all users use.

For writing to your database I would recommend using VBA nonetheless, if thats beyond you then you might want to get busy with it soon as that would probably be the best way for you to enable your users to write.

Comment: HI i'm extremely sorry for my amateur knowledge. id int really understand " Go to the ribbon: Data > From Access. This almost works like a pivot table and is indeed view ",it would be helpful if you could explain it more in detail, i want to get only newly added records in database and place it at the first empty row.

Comment: In excel at the top of the screen you see the part that used to be called the menu? Go to the part called Data, and so on! Furthermore if you are indeed as inexperienced you might be posting in the wrong forum. It is expected the question-asker has a decent knowledge of the programming language and environment he/she is working in. If that is not the case, you are more helped with a training and that environment then with all the lose bits-n-pieces of knowledge we might try to feed you...